# HttpServletRequest request submission in Postman

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, postman

I'm writing my code like this:

```
@RestController
public class WebSSOController {

    @Autowired
    private WebSSOService webSSOService;

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSSOController.class);

    @PostMapping(path = "/generaToken")
    public ResponseEntity<Token> generaToken(HttpServletRequest request) {

        final String host=request.getRemoteAddr();
        final String key = request.getParameter("key");
        final String application = request.getParameter("nomeApp");

        try {
            final Token token=webSSOService.generateToken(host, key, application);
            return new ResponseEntity<Token>(token, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(Message.ERROR_OCCURRED+Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()+": "+ e.getMessage());
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<Token>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .
```

I would like to simulate a request submission using Postman. 
Please, can somebody tell me how can I formulate my request if I have a HttpServletRequest in input to my method?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack.. Shortest way is to implement SWAGGER which will provide you UI based requester and response types. In case you are using spring boot follow https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Comment: What have you tried? What's the concrete problem? You need a POST request, to the path /generaToken, with two parameters key and nomeApp.

Comment: Thank you all! I've solved my problem: when a HttpServletRequest object is in input to a method in Rest Controller class, I don't have to pass parameters because in someway the request is processed itself.

Comment: Generally, in a Post method you have @RequestBody parameters in input, and you have to write in Postman a object in the body of the request (for example, a JSON object, with {"parameter":"value"}). But in this case, you don't have to, it works without writing anything in the body. Thank you again!

Comment: @Nivel23 Can you share your postman inputs?

Comment: @Nivel23 what did you put on Postman?

Answer (score -1):

In postman if you need to put values for "key" parameter and "nomeApp" parameter you can use the Params section of postman where you can give values to your parameters through key and value method and Postman will update the request URL appending the query parameters accordingly.

[image: Screen Shot showing how can we do it in Postman]