# HttpServletRequest request attributes through Postman

Tags: spring-boot, postman

```
@PostMapping("/name")
public String name(HttpServletRequest request,
                                         HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
   String userId = (String)request.getAttribute("user_id");
}
```

I'm using Postman to send POST requests to the API but I'm not able to figure out how to pass values in postman so that I can retrieve userId using request.getAttribute(). I tried a lot of things- Form-data, Params and even Headers on Postman but userId always returns null.

What is the correct way to pass request attributes using postman for a Post request?

Comment: You can check this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59877845/httpservletrequest-request-submission-in-postman)

Comment: That is request.getParameter(). I'm using getAttribute()

Comment: @AlejandroLafourcadeDespaigne I tried passing it that way, still doesn't work for getAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try 'user_id' send in headers
[image]

Then,

get all header values and get key,

> ```
> Map<String, List<String>> headersMap = Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaderNames())    
> .stream()
> .collect(Collectors.toMap(
>     Function.identity(), 
>     h -> Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaders(h))
> ));
> ```

```
headersMap.get('user_id')
```

or only 'user_id'

```
request.getHeader('user_id')
```

Comment: Like I'm working on someone else's code and they're doing it this way. While running it the userId parameter is being null. I'm using Postman to send my request so I need to figure out how to send the request correctly through postman